# Python nosetests with coverage no longer shows missing lines

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

I've been using the following command to run tests and evaluate code coverage for a Python project for over a year now.

```
nosetests -v --with-coverage --cover-package=genhub genhub/*.py
```

The coverage report used to include a column on the far right showing the lines missing coverage.

```
Name                 Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------
genhub/cdhit.py         50      0      8      0   100%   
genhub/exons.py         85     69      8      0    17%   24-40, 48-56, 60-79, 87-107, 129-132, 138-141, 147-150
genhub/fasta.py         76      0     26      0   100%   
genhub/genomedb.py     205    153     48      0    21%   40-43, 53-60, 64-65, 70, 74, 82, 86, 90, 98-99, 103-104, 108-109, 113-114, 118-119, 123-124, 128-129, 143-144, 152-154, 158-160, 164-166, 175, 180, 240-280, 289, 292, 295, 308-317, 323-330, 351-377, 380-386, 396-413, 419-430, 436-443, 449-456
genhub/iloci.py        112     91      8      0    18%   30-46, 54-64, 73-90, 102-118, 127-142, 165-173, 179-183, 189-193, 199-207, 213-225
genhub/mrnas.py        121    108     24      0     9%   30-63, 79-105, 118-158, 178-197, 203-226
genhub/pdom.py          95     68     24      0    23%   31-32, 35, 39, 43, 47, 50-53, 56-59, 62-64, 67-72, 75-106, 116-119, 126-128, 134-141, 148-156
genhub/proteins.py      20     13      2      0    32%   43-53, 94-97
genhub/refseq.py       237    195     44      0    15%   30-46, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 76-86, 89-115, 118-127, 130-178, 189-211, 217-226, 232-242, 248-265, 271-288, 294-297, 303-310, 317-326, 333-374, 380-387
genhub/registry.py     126     90     32      2    24%   48-56, 59-64, 67-69, 72-77, 81-83, 92-94, 103-109, 112-113, 116-117, 142-168, 174-188, 194-201, 207-216, 40->44, 44->48
genhub/stats.py          3      0      0      0   100%   
genhub/tair.py         128     97     22      0    21%   32-42, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 76-79, 82-104, 110-119, 122-154, 165-180, 186-189, 195-203, 210-221
----------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                 1258    884    246      2    27%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 46 tests in 0.033s

FAILED (errors=41)
```

However, the `Missing` column no longer shows up for me (nose version 1.3.7, coverage.py version 4.1).

I'm aware nose is no longer being supported. Is this change related to that, or something in coverage.py, or both?

Comment: See the **Note** here: https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html. What was the previous "working" version you used?

Comment: @busfault I know it was working with coverage.py 4.0.3.

Comment: I've got the same issue. I had `coverage==3.7.1` and `nose==1.3.7` and the line numbers were showing. `coverage==4.1` removed them. Time for me to revert. Please make an issue in their repo https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/new

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In coverage.py 4.1, I fixed a problem with the coverage.py API defaulting two parameters to non-None values.  One of them was `show_missing`.

The best way to fix this in your project is to set `show_missing` in your .coveragerc file:

```
# .coveragerc
[report]
show_missing = True
```

Comment: Is there a convenient way to set show_missing in the nose command rather than needing a .coveragerc?

Answer (score 2):

Beside having a configuration files to set `show_missing` you can also use coverage `set_option` to define it.

```
cov.set_option('report:show_missing', True)
```

I have issue with getting the correct coverage for `models.py`, i solve it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24668174/how-to-test-coverage-properly-with-django-nose).

Then i just add the above lines to show missing line. So my `manage.py` have a part like this:

```
if is_testing:
    import coverage
    cov = coverage.coverage(source=['blog'], omit=['*/tests/*'])
    cov.set_option('report:show_missing', True) #add this
    cov.erase()
    cov.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to revert back to 3.7.1
You can just downgrade to 4.0.0